# How does JavaScript get notified when its message queue becomes empty -> non-empty?

Tags: javascript, concurrency

[This article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop) explains that JavaScript event loop looks like

```
while(queue.waitForMessage()){
  queue.processNextMessage();
}
```

What I'm wondering is how the waitForMessage() function works. From my understanding JavaScript is non-blocking so it doesn't work like it blocks and another thread wakes it up? So how does JavaScript know when to "un-wait" from the empty state?

Comment: It's not real code and would not work in javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article you reference presents that block of code as an illustration only. That's what the structure referred to as the "JavaScript event loop" *conceptually* looks like, but in reality the details are generally much more complicated and dependent upon the runtime environment of the JavaScript implementation code. I'm no JavaScript runtime internals expert, but I'd be willing to bet that the code structure in any real implementation doesn't look much like that at all.

In a web browser, the browser's internal "framework" code might provide a point of registration vaguely similar to JavaScript event handler registration. For something like Node.js, the runtime is dealing with the operating system I/O primitives (etc).

Comment: @zerkms yes; I understand where the MDN article author got that terminology, but it's unfortunate. I'll edit.